# having trouble generating xml attribute with java sax

Tags: java, xml, sax

I am using SAX api in java to convert csv to xml.  I can generate a simple xml file without attribute like

```
<item>
 <item_id>1500</item_id>
 <item_quantity>4</item_quantity>
</item>
```

but I can't find the way to set id and quantity as attribute to item element, like

```
<item id=1500 quantity=4/>
```

All SAX api seems to offer is `startElement`, `character` and `endElement` methods. (I know there is the `attribute` parameter in those method but I can't ever seem to set attribute at all).

Comment: There is an attribute parameter. You can't seem to use it to set attributes. My conclusion: You're using that parameter wrong. Post a sample of how you're trying to set attributes, and we might be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There's some decent sample code [here](http://www.javazoom.net/services/newsletter/xmlgeneration.html) that includes adding attributes.

```
import java.io.*;
// Xerces 1 or 2 additional classes.
import org.apache.xml.serialize.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
[...]
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
// XERCES 1 or 2 additionnal classes.
OutputFormat of = new OutputFormat("XML","ISO-8859-1",true);
of.setIndent(1);
of.setIndenting(true);
of.setDoctype(null,"users.dtd");
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(fos,of);
// SAX2.0 ContentHandler.
ContentHandler hd = serializer.asContentHandler();
hd.startDocument();
// Processing instruction sample.
//hd.processingInstruction("xml-stylesheet","type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"users.xsl\"");
// USER attributes.
AttributesImpl atts = new AttributesImpl();
// USERS tag.
hd.startElement("","","USERS",atts);
// USER tags.
String[] id = {"PWD122","MX787","A4Q45"};
String[] type = {"customer","manager","employee"};
String[] desc = {"Tim@Home","Jack&Moud","John D'oé"};
for (int i=0;i<id.length;i++)
{
  atts.clear();
  atts.addAttribute("","","ID","CDATA",id[i]);
  atts.addAttribute("","","TYPE","CDATA",type[i]);
  hd.startElement("","","USER",atts);
  hd.characters(desc[i].toCharArray(),0,desc[i].length());
  hd.endElement("","","USER");
}
hd.endElement("","","USERS");
hd.endDocument();
fos.close();
```