# Set Attribute Value

Tags: java, xml, sax

How can i set a value to id attribute  during creating an xml file, where id values can be anything, for example it can be id="1" or id="A" or id="k1", id="k2"

```
public void process(String s) throws SAXException {

    try {

        atts.clear();
        k++;
        atts.addAttribute("", "", "id", "", "" + k);
        th.startElement("", "", "trans-unit", atts);
        th.startElement("", "", "target", null);
        th.characters(elements[i].toCharArray(), 0, elements[i].length());
        th.endElement("", "", "target");
        th.endElement("", "", "trans-unit");

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you copied the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250529/set-attribute-of-sax-element), which works for the OP, so your problem must be elsewhere. Please provide more info on what is failing.

Also, take a look at this [easier implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1937994/2302499), maybe that can help you.

### Edit

You just have to change the last parameter of addAttribute

```
atts.addAttribute("", "", "id", "", yourStringOfChoiceHere);
```

addArttibute's doc is [here](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/AttributesImpl.html#addAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). If you're planning to keep the *process* method in your code, you probably want to add the id value as a variable

```
public void process(String s, String idValue) throws SAXException {

...
    atts.addAttribute("", "", "id", "", idValue);
...

}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, i wondering if it possible to set not just an increasing numbers, also  other attribute values to the "id", if yes, how it can be done?

Comment: something like, these values "A-Z" or "i1-i9"

Comment: Like this for example `atts.addAttribute("", "", "id", "", "anything_here");`. addArttibute's doc is [here](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/AttributesImpl.html#addAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (added to the main answer)